# Call a function by its name and arity

Tags: function, erlang, arity

I'm trying to write a function that calls a function with a specified name and arity:

```
my_fun(FunctionName, Arity) ->
    %Call FunctionName/Arity 
.
```

So that calling it like this:

```
my_fun(foo, 3)
```

should result in a call to function `foo/3`.

The problem is, I don't know how to call a function if only its name and arity are specified. The function I'm trying to call is guaranteed to exist in the same module from which I'm trying to call it.

Is it possible to implement this in Erlang, and how?

Comment: What arguments do you want to send to `foo` in this case?

Comment: Something like foo(1,2,3) will do, doesnt really matter in the example. In the real program I'm planing to have a case statement and call it with different arguments depending on Arity.

Comment: `erlang:apply(FunctionName, lists:seq(1, Arity))` ?

Comment: I ended up using apply(?MODULE, FunctionName, [some, args, here]). It works just the way I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `erlang:apply/3` with the first argument being `?MODULE` to refer to the same module, the second one being the name of the function as an atom and the third one being a list containing `Arity` elements:

```
-module(a).
-compile(export_all).

my_fun(FunctionName, Arity) ->
  apply(?MODULE, FunctionName, lists:seq(1, Arity)).

foo(A, B, C) ->
  io:format("~p ~p ~p~n", [A, B, C]).

bar(A, B) ->
  io:format("~p ~p~n", [A, B]).

main() ->
  my_fun(foo, 3),
  my_fun(bar, 2).
```

Output:

```
1> c(a), a:main().
1 2 3
1 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Dogbert. I just wasn't aware of the apply function so I was trying weird things

Answer (score 4):

Not really clear what you want to do...

Does this help you?

```
-module (cf).

-export ([cf/2,test/0,f/1,f/2,f/3]).

cf(F,1) ->
    fun(P1) -> apply(cf,F,[P1]) end;
cf(F,2) ->
    fun(P1,P2) -> apply(cf,F,[P1,P2]) end;
cf(F,3) ->
    fun(P1,P2,P3) -> apply(cf,F,[P1,P2,P3]) end.

f(X) -> lists:seq(1,X).
f(X,Y) -> X+Y.
f(X,Y,Z) -> {X,Y,Z}.

test() ->
    A = cf(f,1),
    B = cf(f,2),
    C = cf(f,3),
    {A(3),B(5,6),C(a,12,"hello")}.

1> c(cf).    
{ok,cf}
2> cf:test().
{[1,2,3],11,{a,12,"hello"}}
```

But this is just hiding the function: `apply(Module,Function,Args)`, I don't see the advantage to do not use it directly.